# Best Practice for multiple AJAX requests in React?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm working on a personal project using React, in which I want to render a handful of components, each presenting data from different cities using Yahoo's weather API.

Initially, I was mapping over an array containing the cities I want data for, sending each city down to a component that makes the AJAX request, the result being 5-6 different components that each made their own call.  That works fine if I just want to render current conditions or the high and low for several different cities.

But I would like to use React Router to give users the ability to click a city, causing a re-render that shows details and a 10-day forecast for that city ***only***. The problem I'm running into is the current structure of the project. Because I'm mapping over the array of cities in the parent so I can pass that into the API URL, I'm stuck rendering all of the forecast components.

What would be a better way to structure the project and make the AJAX request so that one view is the several weather components and the other is the single detail view and 10-day forecast for that city?

```
class App extends Component {

 PLACES = [
   { city: "chattanooga", state: "tn"},
   { city: "easton", state: "md"},
   { city: "new york", state: "ny"},
   { city: "norfolk", state: "va"},
   { city: "milford", state: "de"},
   { city: "bangkok", state: null}
 ]

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="weather-container">
       {
         this.PLACES.map( (place, id) => {
           return <Weather key={place.city} id={id} city={place.city} 
                  state={place.state} />
         })
       }
     </div>
   )
  }
}

export default App
```

So that's the parent component mapping over the `PLACES` array to render the 6 `<Weather />` components. And then in the `<Weather />` component I'm making my AJAX request in `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22${this.props.city}%2C%2$${this.props.state}%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys`)
    .then(res => {
      let data = res.data.query.results.channel;
      this.setState({ data : data });
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Weather` component, you should have a `<Link>` to a new component and the route would look like `weather/:location`. The `:location` notation means that you can accept anything here, like `chattanooga`. If you need to pass both city and state, just do `weather/:city/:state` This route will accept your params and you can then use those to re-call the API for the specific city you want to see and its 10-day forecast inside of your new component.

You can access the param inside of your new component by calling `this.props.match.params.location` or `this.props.match.params.city`, etc.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but wouldn't doing that in the `<Weather />` component ender 6 different `<Forecast />` components, because of the `.map()` in the parent component of `<Weather />`? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: There is only one new component I'm suggesting you create. Once you click on a city / state, it will be called. Once you click on another city or state, it is called again, the same component with different params and therefore different API call / different data. Not 6 different ones.